# Why context is not considered when selecting typeclass instance in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I understand that when having

```
instance (Foo a) => Bar a
instance (Xyy a) => Bar a
```

GHC doesn't consider the contexts, and the instances are reported as duplicate.

What is counterintuitive, that (I guess) after selecting an instance, it still needs to check if the context matches, and if not, discard the instance. So why not reverse the order, and discard instances with non-matching contexts, and proceed with the remaining set.

Would this be intractable in some way? I see how it could cause more constraint resolution work upfront, but just as there is `UndecidableInstances` / `IncoherentInstances`, couldn't there be a `ConsiderInstanceContexts` when "I know what I am doing"?

Comment: Which instance should GHC choose if `a` is a `Foo` and a `Xyy` ?

Comment: @mb14: An arbitrary. (`IncoherentInstances` already does something similar, and I can live with that).

Comment: Indeed, the only difference appears to be that `IncoherentInstances` allow GHC to commit to either instance, possibly discarding one with a satisfiable context and committing to the unsatisfiable one (which will trigger an error). This question instead asks why GHC has no `BacktrackOnContextFailures` flag, if I understand correctly, so that the correct instance is eventually tried. It will surely lead to intractability in the worst cases, but we already have `UndecidableInstances` which can significantly impact performance.

Answer (score 5):

This breaks the open-world assumption. Assume:

```
class B1 a
class B2 a
class T a
```

If we allow constraints to disambiguate instances, we may write

```
instance B1 a => T a
instance B2 a => T a
```

And may write

```
instance B1 Int
```

Now, if I have

```
f :: T a => a
```

Then `f :: Int` works. But, the open world assumption says that, once something works, adding more instances cannot break it. Our new system doesn't obey:

```
instance B2 Int
```

will make `f :: Int` ambiguous. Which implementation of `T` should be used?

Another way to state this is that you've broken coherence. For typeclasses to be coherent means that there is only one way to satisfy a given constraint. In normal Haskell, a constraint `c` has only one implementation. Even with overlapping instances, coherence generally holds true. The idea is that `instance T a` and `instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} T Int` do not break coherence, because GHC can't be tricked into using the former instance in a place where the latter would do. (You *can* trick it with orphans, but you shouldn't.) Coherence, at least to me, seems somewhat desirable. Typeclass usage is "hidden", in some sense, and it makes sense to enforce that it be unambiguous. You can also break coherence with `IncoherentInstances` and/or `unsafeCoerce`, but, y'know.

In a category theoretic way, the category `Constraint` is *thin*: there is at most one `instance`/arrow from one `Constraint` to another. We first construct two arrows `a : () => B1 Int` and `b : () => B2 Int`, and then we break thinness by adding new arrows `x_Int : B1 Int => T Int`, `y_Int : B2 Int => T Int` such that `x_Int . a` and `y_Int . b` are both arrows `() => T Int` that are not identical. Diamond problem, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer you question as to why this is the case. Note, however, that you can always define a newtype wrapper to disambiguate between the two instances:

```
newtype FooWrapper a = FooWrapper a
newtype XyyWrapper a = XyyWrapper a

instance (Foo a) => Bar (FooWrapper a)
instance (Xyy a) => Bar (XyyWrapper a)
```

This has the added advantage that by passing around either a FooWrapper or a XyyWrapper you explicitly control which of the two instances you'd like to use if your a happens to satisfy both.

Comment: Sure. My use-case would be more like "select a best instance", without the client having to wrap/know anything. For example having a `LinearSearch`, `BinarySearch` and `Search` class, where `Search` defaults to binary search if the instance exists, linear search otherwise (if exists).

(Well, arbitrary choice would  not be good enough here, more like an ordered choice, but let's put that aside).

Comment: For fun, let's not consider the alternative of making explicit instances of `Search` for each datatype.

Comment: I see that this is a thought experiment and an interesting question (which I cannot answer). However, FWIW, I would consider it a bad design for the compiler to make arbitrary or even nondeterministic choices that completely alter the behaviour of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Classes are a bit weird. The original idea (which still pretty much works) is a sort of syntactic sugar around what would otherwise be `data` statements. For example you can imagine:

```
data Num a = Num {plus :: a -> a -> a, ... , fromInt :: Integer -> a}
numInteger :: Num Integer
numInteger = Num (+) ... id
```

then you can write functions which have e.g. type:

```
test :: Num x -> x -> x -> x -> x
test lib a b c = a + b * (abs (c + b))
    where (+) = plus lib
          (*) = times lib
          abs = absoluteValue lib
```

So the idea is "we're going to automatically derive all of this library code." The question is, how do we find the library that we want? It's easy if we have a library of type `Num Int`, but how do we extend it to "constrained instances" based on functions of type:

```
fooLib :: Foo x -> Bar x
xyyLib :: Xyy x -> Bar x
```

The **present solution** in Haskell is to do a type-pattern-match on the output-types of those functions and propagate the inputs to the resulting declaration. But when there's two outputs of the same type, we would need a combinator which merges these into:

```
eitherLib :: Either (Foo x) (Xyy x) -> Bar x
```

and basically the problem is that there is no good constraint-combinator of this kind right now. That's your objection.

Well, that's true, but there are ways to achieve something morally similar in practice. Suppose we define some functions with types:

```
data F
data X
foobar'lib :: Foo x -> Bar' x F
xyybar'lib :: Xyy x -> Bar' x X
bar'barlib :: Bar' x y -> Bar x
```

Clearly the `y` is a sort of "phantom type" threaded through all of this, but it remains powerful because given that we want a `Bar x` we will propagate the need for a `Bar' x y` and given the need for the `Bar' x y` we will generate either a `Bar' x X` or a `Bar' x y`. So with phantom types and multi-parameter type classes, we get the result we want.

More info: https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap

Answer (score 2):

Adding backtracking would make instance resolution require exponential time, in the worst case.

Essentially, instances become logical statements of the form

```
P(x) => R(f(x)) /\ Q(x) => R(f(x))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(P(x) \/ Q(x)) => R(f(x))
```

Computationally, the cost of this check is (in the worst case)

```
c_R(n) = c_P(n-1) + c_Q(n-1)
```

assuming `P` and `Q` have similar costs

```
c_R(n) = 2 * c_PQ(n-1)
```

which leads to exponential growth.

To avoid this issue, it is important to have fast ways to choose a branch, i.e. to have clauses of the form

```
((fastP(x) /\ P(x)) \/ (fastQ(x) /\ Q(x))) => R(f(x))
```

where `fastP` and `fastQ` are computable in constant time, and are incompatible so that at most one branch needs to be visited.

Haskell decided that this "fast check" is head compatibility (hence disregarding contexts). It could use other fast checks, of course -- it's a design decision.

Comment: Basic Hindley-Milner type inference already requires exponential time in the worse case, and yet we do it, so this isn't an argument against backtracking. Programmers don't tend to trigger the worst case of HM, which is why it isn't a problem. Would programmers tend to trigger exponential cases for instance resolution with constraints?

Comment: @Gilles That's true. I somehow always assumed that programmers would trigger exponential blow up with constraints, but I think there's no empirical evidence for that. More to the point, we already allow undecidable instances and undecidable type families which can lead to even larger costs. So, maybe an extension could add backtracking. I still think that the blow up is the main reason why Haskell has no backtracking -- when it was first designed, type classes had many more constraints (no undecidable stuff, for instance).