# Why not a Phantom class which extends Functor Contravariant?

Tags: haskell, covariance, functor, contravariance, library-design

I am playing around with the [`Data.Functor.Contravariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html). The [`phantom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:phantom) method caught my eye:

```
phantom :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f a -> f b
phantom x = () <$ x $< ()
```

Or, more specifically, the annotation to it:

> If `f` is both `Functor` and `Contravariant` then by the time you factor in the laws of each of those classes, it can't actually use it's argument in any meaningful capacity.
> This method is surprisingly useful. Where both instances exist and are lawful we have the following laws: `fmap f ≡ phantom`, `contramap f ≡ phantom`

Since `fmap f ≡ contramap f ≡ phantom`, why do we need `Contravariant` and `Functor` instances? Isn't it handier to do this thing the other way: create an instance for one class `Phantom`, which introduces the `phantom` method, <del>and then *automatically derive* instances for `Functor` and `Contravariant`</del>?

```
class Phantom f where
    phantom :: f a -> f b
```

```
instance Phantom f => Functor f where
    fmap _f = phantom

instance Phantom f => Contravariant f where
    contramap _f = phantom
```

We will rid the programmer of the necessity to rewrite this `phantom` twice (to implement `fmap` and `contramap`, which are `const phantom`, as stated in the annotation) when implementing instances for `Contravariant` and `Functor`. We will allow writing one instance instead of two! Besides, it seems nice and idiomatic to me to have classes for all 4 cases of variance: `Functor`, [`Contravariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Contravariant), [`Invariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.4/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html#t:Invariant) (yet, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708805/how-to-use-data-functor-invariant/48710624#48710624) suggest using [`Profunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Profunctor) interface instead of [`Invariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.4/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html#t:Invariant)), and `Phantom`.

Also, isn't it a more *efficient* approach? `() <$ x $< ()` requires two traverses (as much as we can traverse a phantom functor...), as long as the programmer might carry this transformation out a bit faster. As far as I understand, the current `phantom` method can't be overridden.

So, why didn't the library developers choose this way? What are the pros and cons of the current design and the design I spoke of?

Comment: `phantom` is not a method of either `Functor` or `Contravariant`. You don't need "rewrite it twice" or even once.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin You do, to implement `fmap` and `contramap`, which are `const phantom`. Sorry for bad wording

Comment: Well, there's, like... `Proxy` and `Const` and... what else, exactly? (Indeed, every phantom type is `Const` in disguise.) You're saving maybe five seconds of programmer time like once every ten years. Feels hard to get worked up over that.

Comment: Hm would this be safe: `phantom = unsafeCoerce :: Functor f => Contravariant f => f a -> f b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the overlapping instances mentioned by amalloy you could define a newtype which can be used with DerivingVia:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

import Data.Functor.Contravariant hiding (phantom)

class (Functor f, Contravariant f) => Phantom f where
  phantom :: f a -> f b

newtype WrappedPhantom f a = WrappedPhantom (f a)

instance Phantom f => Phantom (WrappedPhantom f) where
  phantom (WrappedPhantom x) = WrappedPhantom (phantom x)

instance Phantom f => Functor (WrappedPhantom f) where
  fmap _ = phantom

instance Phantom f => Contravariant (WrappedPhantom f) where
  contramap _ = phantom

-- example of usage:

data SomePhantom a = SomePhantom
  deriving (Functor, Contravariant) via WrappedPhantom SomePhantom

instance Phantom SomePhantom where
  phantom SomePhantom = SomePhantom
```

It's not quite as convenient as having the instances automatically, but it still means that you don't have to implement Functor and Contravariant instances manually.

Comment: Very nice, but `Functor` and `Contravariant` should surely be superclasses of `Phantom`!

Comment: @dfeuer you're right, and I think everything still works with those added.

Comment: Daniel Wagner points out it can even take `Traversable`: `traverse _ = pure . phantom`.

Answer (score 6):

There are many types which are an instance of Functor but not of Phantom, and likewise Contravariant. For such types, the structure you propose would be a big problem because of overlapping instances.

```
instance Phantom f => Functor f
```

does not mean "if `f` is a Phantom then it is also a Functor". Only instance heads are searched during typeclass resolution, and the constraints come in later. This is related to the [open world assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885067/why-context-is-not-considered-when-selecting-typeclass-instance-in-haskell). So you are declaring a Functor instance for `f`, a totally unconstrained type variable which will overlap with every other possible instance declaration.

Comment: Huh, that’s interesting effect. I didn’t know about it, thank you. Anyway, even if we drop those instances, wouldn’t it still be handier to have a chance to implement `phantom` in own terms? Idiomatically speaking, phantom variance is a separate case both from co- and contravariance

Comment: How would you imagine doing that? Would yo write `class (Functor f, Contravariant f) => Phantom f where ...`? What would be the point in that?

Comment: Defining `Phantom` just like we define the rest - without any extensions. I. e. `class Phantom f where phantom :: f a -> f b`. Even though the idea behind the implementation is cool, I cannot see much point in it: (sticking to default `<$` and `$<`) we run both `fmap` and `contramap`, which are the same as `const phantom`. I. e. to run `phantom` we run `const phantom` **twice** via two **separate** functions

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor The problem with that is that you can then only use `phantom` on a type if that type's author has written the Phantom instance. And authors usually won't. You'll end up wanting the standalone `phantom` function anyway, for authors who don't declare an instance. Using the class version would be slightly more efficient but less general.

Comment: why do we assume the author would write `Functor` and `Contravariant` instances? Besides, what is stopping us from implementing an instance ourselves?

Comment: If we're allowed to change `base` we can do better than overlapping: we can use `DefaultSignatures` and write `class Functor f where fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b; default fmap :: Phantom f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b; fmap _ = phantom`. ...but if we're going to do something like that, the `foldMapDefault` from `Data.Traversable` seems like it would apply more often. It is strictly more general in the sense that any phantom type can be made traversable.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, most authors do write `Functor` instances when they can, at least for exported types. `Contravariant` is less universal, but still reasonably popular. But phantom type variables are very often used internally, and when exposed are often artificially forced to `nominal`, with neither `Functor` nor `Contravariant` Instances. The main exception I can think of is `Const`, for which the function version is just fine.

Comment: @DanielWagner, oh, good point about `Traversable`!

Comment: @DanielWagner Can you, please elaborate on why you call `Traversable` strictly more general? Doesn't `Traversable` extend `Functor`? Every `Traversable` instance can be made into a `Functor` via [`fmapDefault`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:fmapDefault) (thus, if every phantom type can be made into a `Traversable`, the same goes for `Functor`). I guess I'm missing which *generality* it is.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor A default for `fmap` that works for any `Traversable` is more general than a default for `fmap` that works for any `Phantom`, because any `Phantom` can be made `Traversable`.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could really do would be something like this:

```
class (Functor f, Contravariant f) => Phantom f where
  phantom :: f a -> f b
  phantom x = () <$ x $< ()
```

The trouble is that people probably won't be interested in taking the time to instantiate the class.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t edit the question right now. For now, can you, please answer the question I asked concerning the usefulness of this default implementation under @amalloy’s post? I will add it to the post later

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, I really don't understand what you're getting at with `const phantom`; maybe amalloy can answer your question.